# Wierd issues regarding Scan Endscan in foxpro 2.6

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I got one weird usage problems about SCAN to ENDSCAN loop in Foxpro 2.6.

Let said my tables got 7 records under first fields column with name "alphabet" locate under table name "table1", first until fifth records started with "A" from actual browse view.

### alphabet

A
A
A
A
A
B
B

- then I would like to use my following code to invoke deletion based on condition with alphabet must equal to "A".

### Code Example :

use table1 alias table1 in 0 EXCLU

sele table1
scan for alphabet = 'A'

dele 
  pack

end scan

- Here is the problem comes, only four record believes is deleted but retains first record "A" is undeleted.
- Here is result after perform the deletion from above.

### alphabet

A
B
B

I've think about this problem maybe one particular of bug problem gather in foxpro 2.6. Hope someone could help me to get rid on this matters. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a bug. This is because you're PACKing inside the loop. The record pointer is always on record 1 after a PACK command.

Besides that, what you're doing is not a good idea. In general, it's better to design so that you PACK only rarely as part of a maintenance operation. If you really think you need to PACK here, you should still wait and do it only once, after the loop.

Comment: Delete the records as part of the SCAN loop, then do one pack at the end.

Comment: Also note that if your SCAN...ENDSCAN loop really is that simple, you can replace it with a DELETE ALL FOR alphabet='A'

Comment: Well no, you either want to DELETE FROM mytable WHERE alphabet="A" or DELETE FOR alphabet = "A" IN mytable

Comment: Mine is the non-SQL version of DELETE.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need ALL if you're supplying a scope.